# MySQL Select query values

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
id   name       value
1    primary    value1
2    secudary   value1
3    primary    value1
4    secudary   value1
5    primary    value3
6    secudary   value3
```

I need to `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1"`

But I can't select information from primary and secondary field at the same time.
 
I want to check if there are any record for `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1" and name = "primary"` If there are record I use this result, if there are NO record I search for `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1" and name = "secundary"`

Any idea?

Comment: separate primary and secundary columns

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a variable, select records to load the variable, check if it has value and use an if statement for your select. (I do this in a stored procedure).

```
declare $found int;
set $found = null;
set $found= (select id FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1" and name = "primary" limit 1);

if ($found is null) then
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1" and name = "secundary";
else
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value = "value1" and name = "primary";
end if;
```

Comment: If this was helpful, please mark it as an answer. Thanks.